# Problema al obtener el archivo appsettings.json

Tags: c#, .net, maui, appsettings

Tengo una solución con MAUI en la que presento un modelo de capas para los distintos proyectos:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ahí se está viendo que appsettings está en 3.Presentation y necesito obtenerlo en EmailSender dentro del 2.BussinessLogic.
appsettings.json tiene la propiedad de Acción de compilación como Recurso incrustado para que pueda leerse desde MauiProgram.cs al iniciar la aplicación:

```
public static MauiApp CreateMauiApp()
        {
            var builder = MauiApp.CreateBuilder();
            builder
                .UseMauiApp<App>()
                .ConfigureFonts(fonts =>
                {
                    fonts.AddFont("OpenSans-Regular.ttf", "OpenSansRegular");
                    fonts.AddFont("OpenSans-Semibold.ttf", "OpenSansSemibold");
                });

            using var stream = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()
                .GetManifestResourceStream("_3.Presentation.appsettings.json");
            var config = new ConfigurationBuilder().AddJsonStream(stream).Build();

            builder.Logging.AddDebug();

            return builder.Build();
        }
```

Ahora tengo la problemática de poder usar la configuración de la aplicación en dicho proyecto, el cual está referenciado en las dependencias de 3.Presentation.

```
string basePath = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory;
            string appSettingsPath = Path.Combine(basePath, "..", "3.Presentation", "appsettings.json");

            IConfiguration configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                .AddJsonFile(appSettingsPath, optional: false, reloadOnChange: true)
                .Build();

            _remitent = configuration["remitent"];
            _password = configuration["passremitent"];
```

Cuando trato de obtener el json me dice que no es posible encontrarlo. Le he llegado a pasar incluso la ruta completa desde C y aun así no lo encuentra. ¿Qué tengo que hacer?

Comment: Yo creo que `EmailSender` no tiene porque leer el appsetting, no debería depender de ello. `EmailSender`  debería implementar una función que reciba como argumento el `remitent` y el `passremitent` de esta manera es independiente de una archivo de configuración y es usable en cualquier lado (incluyendo en pruebas unitarias). Luego en el proyecto de presentación, que es donde entiendo envías los correos, ya se lee el appsetting entonces tienes los valores para poder ingresarlos a dicha función

Comment: Pudiera ser, pero ya no solo por funcionalidad, quiero saber cómo poder implementarlo.